# Cite only first author and year

Tags: biblatex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite*{kastenholz}, \citeyear{kastenholz}
\end{document}
```

I am look for a way to cite only the first author (or more if it is not unique) and the year with one command. Kind of `fullcite{}` but the other way around. I couldn't find this in the docu.

I need this on a specific part of the paper. The this should work "local" and not affect any global settings of the document.
I want to use this in a table to reference papers where the data comes from but with minimal space usage in the table.

Comment: You've tagged this `biblatex`, but your MWE doesn't use `biblatex` (or any package for bibliography). Are you actually using one?

Answer (score 4):

You could create a new cite command, from the ones available, to do what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand\mycite[1]{\AtNextCite{\defcounter{maxnames}{1}}\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1}}

\begin{document}
\mycite{kastenholz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update**: As pointed out by moewe in the comments, this approach, albeit simple, has relevant limitations. It won't deal with pre- and post-notes (though it could be adapted to deal with one of them) and also not handle multiple entries. If this is enough for your case, then fine, otherwise, for a more general solution using `\DeclareCiteCommand` is preferred (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398595/105447).

Comment: If this is what @buhtz wants I'll just delete my answer.

Comment: @AlanMunn, I was also going in the same direction as you. But given your interaction, it sounds like this is what the OP wants. Let's hear from him anyway. But I'd leave your answer if I were you, for if other people stumble into this question later, it offers a more standard way to do what the title states.

Comment: Combining several biblatex-`\cite...` commands is usually inferior to defining a specific command with `\DeclareCiteCommand`. The command in your answer has problems when multiple entries are cited and also with pre- and postnotes.

Comment: True @moewe, I'm aware of the limitations of this approach. But thought this should be enough for the purposes of "using this in a table". We haven't heard from the OP yet, but if you think it is best to keep the site cleaner of these "hacks", I can provide a proper cite command.

Comment: @moewe, I was trying to do it for the sake of learning and for the fun of it, but couldn't make it. So, if you care to provide an answer, defining a proper cite command with `\DeclareCiteCommand` I won't be troubled at all, rather the contrary.

Comment: I have seen too many people use commands like `\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1}` as a 'normal' cite command. In this case it might be enough, but it would be bad if people thought this is a good idea in general.

Comment: @moewe, you are right that the limitations should be clearly stated, for the purposes of future reference. I'll edit the question and do so. By the way, +1 for your answer, top-notch as usual.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want an author-year type citation. So load `biblatex` with the `authoryear` style.

If you really want only the first author to show up, then use `maxnames=1` or `maxcitenames=1` which will render the example citation as *Kastenholz et al. (2006)*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\textcite{kastenholz}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: I specified my question depending on your answer. I need the global biblatex settings.

Comment: @buhtz I'm sorry but then I don't understand what you are doing. You are using the numeric style, but need a specific author/year citation in one place?

Answer (score 2):

You can define a new command for that like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage[style=numeric, labeldateparts]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newbibmacro{aycite}{%
  \defcounter{maxnames}{1}%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{labeltitle}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printlabeldateextra}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\aycite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{aycite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}} 

\begin{document}
\aycite{kastenholz}
\end{document}
```

I would have preferred to use `mincitenames=1, maxcitenames=1, uniquelist=true` instead of `\defcounter{maxnames}{1}`, but that would have been against your wish to not change any settings.
It is only possible to fulfil the 'or more if it is not unique' desideratum with `mincitenames=1, maxcitenames=1, uniquelist=true`.
Since you use a `numeric` style it is unlikely that the three options would impact other citations, but not impossible (if you use `\textcite` there could be changes, if you only use `\cite` there should not be a problem).

I introduced the `labeldateparts` option, but that does not impact other commands.